# How to parse a text file in java?

Tags: java, text-parsing

I have a text file in the following url.

```
http://hosted.stats.com/ifb2009/data.asp?file=en/chlg_standings.txt
```

I want to parse this text file and display the data as groups, teams etc. Can anyone please let me know how to parse text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a java question, not an android specific question.

The best is to use a `BufferedReader` on your file (or stream).
Then use `readLine` to get one line.

Then use `String.split` or `String.indexOf` to parse your data.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best thing to do is use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) that way you can easily specify your used delimiters and read data in its correct form (readXXX()). Also you can use the same logic independent of where the file is from by replacing the Stream in the constructor with another.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split(..)` if it is simple.  If it is more complex, you could use [regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)